# How to keep translated pages related to original in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, multilingual, goal-tracking

I have a multilingual website.

The URL structure is like:

- example.com/en/page
- example.com/es/pagina

So, the first term is the language and then a slug for the page in the right language.

I would like to create a funnel where both pages count as the same goal.

How can I keep them related?

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to coding, but to comment, have you tried using regex?

Comment: If  you want to solve this in code you could pass in a language neutral page path into your pageview calls and store the original path in a custom dimension (which obviously would have side effects and would not work for data that's already collected).  Or use an event with an event based goal (but then you wouldn't have a funnel visualization).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about how to create funnels in Google Analytics and is not programing related.

Comment: Since this is apparently off topic I wrote a short description of this could be done here: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/translated-pages-to-original-in-ga/

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff

Thank you very much for your article. This is exactly what I was looking for. I will definitely use it when I upgrade my site to multilanguage!

I am sorry about this post being off topic. Since there is some code needed, I thought this was the right place.

Comment: I'm actually not sure about the OT thing (wasn't my vote), but it was a good opportunity for an article (vanity thy name is blog). Since this was both code and helpful I will turn this into an answer when I have the time.